# VGG16 pre-trained model is not giving accurate Image Similarity in scala

Tags: scala, keras, cosine-similarity, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I'm trying to calculate **similarity** between two Images to determine that whether they belong to same person or not, for that I'm using **deeplearning4j**, **keras** and **VGG16 pre-trained model (vgg16_dl4j_inference.zip this model downloads automatically just after running the program, Its size is about 513.7MB)**.

I'm trying to implement it in **scala (version 2.13.4)** with **sbt (version 1.9.6)**, here is my code.

**build.sbt**:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "AddExternalLib"
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.deeplearning4j" % "deeplearning4j-core" % "1.0.0-beta7"
  , "org.deeplearning4j" % "deeplearning4j-modelimport" % "1.0.0-beta7"
  , "org.deeplearning4j" % "deeplearning4j-nn" % "1.0.0-beta7"
  , "org.deeplearning4j" % "deeplearning4j-zoo" % "1.0.0-beta7"
  , "org.nd4j" % "nd4j-native-platform" % "1.0.0-beta7"
  , "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.4.7"
)
```

here is my main class.

**Deeplearning.scala**

```
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.graph.ComputationGraph
import org.deeplearning4j.zoo.model.VGG16
import org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray
import org.datavec.image.loader.NativeImageLoader
import org.nd4j.linalg.factory.Nd4j

object Deeplearning extends App {
  val vgg16 = VGG16.builder().build()
  val model: ComputationGraph = vgg16.initPretrained().asInstanceOf[ComputationGraph]

  val loader = new NativeImageLoader(224, 224, 3)
  val image1 = loader.asMatrix("image1.jpg")
  val image2 = loader.asMatrix("image2.jpeg")

  val input1 = Nd4j.expandDims(image1, 0).reshape(Array(1, 3, 224, 224))
  val input2 = Nd4j.expandDims(image2, 0).reshape(Array(1, 3, 224, 224))

  val embeddings1: INDArray = model.outputSingle(input1)
  val embeddings2: INDArray = model.outputSingle(input2)
  val cosineSimilarity: Double = cosineSimilarity(embeddings1, embeddings2)

  println(s"Cosine Similarity: $cosineSimilarity")

  def cosineSimilarity(vec1: INDArray, vec2: INDArray): Double = {
    val dotProduct: Double = vec1.mul(vec2).sumNumber().doubleValue()
    val magnitude1: Double = Math.sqrt(vec1.mul(vec1).sumNumber().doubleValue())
    val magnitude2: Double = Math.sqrt(vec2.mul(vec2).sumNumber().doubleValue())

    dotProduct / (magnitude1 * magnitude2)
  }
}
```

The problem is that it calculates similarity of **identical images** fine, but in case if I give my **current and 2,3 years old image** it considers them as Images of **different** person although they are same.

**Output for identical Images:**

Cosine Similarity: **1.0**

**Output for Current and 2,3 years old Images:**

Cosine Similarity: **0.08223503419296793**

although images quality is fine , even if I crop faces from images and calculate similarity, still it is not working accurately.

**Guide me how can I increase accuracy?**